# Adding a photo to a contact

Tags: salesforce-service-cloud

how do I paste the photo of the contact, in the contact's photo field which is located on the "Contact Detail Page"?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7b8s.png)

Photo can be added in Contact through social networking.
Apart from this is there is any option to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add photo to this place. This is only for social media.

You can create custom field to store image. Text Area (Rich) can do this.